# How to set date-picker with JQuery 3.3.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have to set date picker for input fields in few different forms. In the past I have used jQuery date-picker but for this project I use Bootstrap 3 so there is another method that is available. Here is example that I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepick').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<!---*** Start: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---*** End: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
<!---*** Start: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!---*** End: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->

<script language="javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="form-group required">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepick" name="frmSaveOffice_startdt" id="frmSaveOffice_startdt" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that snippet above works but there is few things that I would like to modify. First I would like input field to be `readonly`. User should be able to click on calendar icon and then chose `date only`. I do not need time next to the date. Clicking on the icon will prevent user to enter what ever they want. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this with date-picker in bootstrap and jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to move `datepick` class from `<input>` to the `<div>` with the `input-group` class, to let the user open the picker clicking on the calendar icon.

Then you have to add readonly property to the input and set [`ignoreReadonly`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#ignorereadonly) option to `true`.

Use [`format`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option to customize date format and to *hide* timepicker, as the docs says:

> See [momentjs' docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for valid formats. Format also dictates what components are shown, e.g. `MM/dd/YYYY` will not display the time picker.

Here a live sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepick').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    ignoreReadonly: true
  });
});
```

```html
<!---*** Start: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---*** End: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
<!---*** Start: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!---*** End: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->

<script language="javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="form-group required">
  <div class="input-group datepick">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frmSaveOffice_startdt" id="frmSaveOffice_startdt" required readonly>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attributes to you input element

```
readonly data-date-ignore-readonly="true" data-date-format="MM/DD/yyyy"
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepick').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<!---*** Start: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---*** End: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
<!---*** Start: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!---*** End: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->

<script language="javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="form-group required">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input readonly data-date-ignore-readonly="true" data-date-format="MM/DD/yyyy" type="text" class="form-control datepick" name="frmSaveOffice_startdt" id="frmSaveOffice_startdt" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```